# How to know if the string::split is on one char or another inside that method?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a simple `to_title()` method to titleize words with spaces and dashes inside.

PLAYGROUND HERE: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=62592941bde3c46469f1fead08842e88

```rust
fn to_title(s: &mut String) {
    let mut res = "".to_string();

    for word in s.split(|c| c == ' ' || c == '-') {
        if !res.is_empty() {
            res.push(' ') // how can I know here if the split is on ' ' or on '-'?
        }

        let mut word = word.to_string();

        uc_first(&mut word);

        res.push_str(&word)
    }

    *s = res
}
```

1. how can I know here if the split is on `' '` or on `'-'` to add `' '` or `'-'` on line 6?
2. is there a way to use `char::is_whitespace()` instead of `' '`?
3. is there a faster way?

Comment: I think you have to manually find `' '` and `'-'`. And de facto reimplement your own split.

Comment: Yeah, this is the question for.

Comment: So what do you want? You don't know how to do it? You want me to show you a draft?

Comment: Those questions are for me important. I think I cannot use .split anymore now that I need to split for dashes and not only for white spaces, right?

Comment: You don't need to manually loop over chars. (1) One option is to use `split_inclusive`, which will keep the trailing spaces in the substrings it returns. You can then use `strip_suffix` to remove the trailing space or dash. Another option is to split twice, once for spaces, once for dashes. (2) `|c| c.is_whitespace() || c == '-'`.

Comment: @PitaJ Wouldn't it be slower, since you have to walk slice to strip the end of it?

Comment: It could be slower.

Comment: Returning a value through a mutable reference parameter is very unidiomatic in Rust, and is probably leading to extra allocations in your code.

Comment: @PitaJ this is another issue I'm trying to understand. Can you please hint me what is the idiomatic signature for these kind of helpers?

Comment: .split_inclusive fixes this problem!

Comment: @Pitaj you can answer indicating `.split_inclusive()` and I can accept your answer. For the problem you indicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73990867/how-to-know-if-the-stringsplit-is-on-one-char-or-another-inside-that-method?noredirect=1#comment130644260_73990867, can you show me a better code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do, using `split_inclusive`:

```
pub fn to_title(s: &mut String) {
    let mut res = "".to_string();

    // Split on any whitespace or dash
    for word in s.split_inclusive(|c: char| c.is_whitespace() || c == '-') {
        // Extract the whitespace or dash from the end, if it exists
        if let Some((i, suffix)) = word.rmatch_indices(|c: char| c.is_whitespace() || c == '-').next() {
            // If this word has whitespace or '-' at the end,
            // split the word up to the suffix, process the word,
            // then push the word and suffix
            let word = uc_first(&word[..i]);
            res.push_str(&word);
            res.push_str(suffix);
        } else {
            // If this is the last word,
            // just process and push it.
            let word = uc_first(word);
            res.push_str(&word);
        }
    }

    *s = res
}
```

It may be more optimal to write a custom splitter that returns the previous segment and the suffix separately, in order to avoid needing to extract the suffix after the fact. Though that should be exceptionally quick, since it only ever needs to check one character.

---

### Some idiomatic recommendations

If you aren't operating on the input string in place, you should pretty much always accept an `&str` instead. So `to_title` and `uc_first` should be changed to the following:

```
pub fn to_title(s: &str) -> String { ... }
pub fn uc_first(s: &str) -> String { ... }
```

`String::new()` does not allocate, so this can actually avoids allocations overall.

Final version:

```
pub fn to_title(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut res = String::new();

    for word in s.split_inclusive(|c: char| c.is_whitespace() || c == '-') {
        if let Some((i, suffix)) = word.rmatch_indices(|c: char| c.is_whitespace() || c == '-').next() {
            // If this word has whitespace or '-' at the end,
            // split the word up to the suffix, process the word,
            // then push the word and suffix
            let word = uc_first(&word[..i]);
            res.push_str(&word);
            res.push_str(suffix);
        } else {
            // If this is the last word,
            // just process and push it.
            let word = uc_first(word);
            res.push_str(&word);
        }
    }

    res
}

pub fn uc_first(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut c = s.chars();

    match c.next() {
        None => String::new(),
        Some(f) => f.to_uppercase().collect::<String>() + c.as_str(),
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d9eafaed87d0465709fdcdae9bb598d1)

Comment: Ok. I'll now study this. In the meantime I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73991634/is-this-an-idiomatic-way-of-writing-these-helpers because of your comment.

Comment: Can I ask you why the `match`? Is there any particular case you wanna test? I'm ok even without the `match`.

Comment: Good point. Originally I was going to handle `-` separately but I didn't end up needing to. It can just be an `if let` instead, I edited my answer.