# Is this an idiomatic way of writing these helpers?

Tags: rust

I'm writing the below helpers to use them everywhere in my app like this:

```rust
impl Player {
    pub fn set_email(&mut self, mut email: String) -> Result<()> {
        trim_all_spaces(&mut email);
        
        if email.is_empty() {
            // return Err
        }

        self.email = email;

        Ok(())
    }

    fn set_firstname(&mut self, mut firstname: String) -> Result<()> {
        to_name(&mut firstname);

        if firstname.is_empty() {
            // return Err
        }

        self.firstname = firstname;

        Ok(())
    }
}

pub fn trim_all_spaces(s: &mut String) {
    s.retain(|c| !c.is_whitespace());
}

pub fn to_name(s: &mut String) {
    trim_useless_space(s);

    s.retain(|c| c.is_whitespace() || c.is_alphabetic());

    *s = s.trim().to_string();
}
```

Is this an idiomatic way of writing these helpers?

Comment: What are "this helpers"? Is it just `trim_all_spaces` and `to_name`? If so, they are already quite idiomatic. You could put them in some helper module, but that's it. One thing you could try adding is to return `&mut String` from this functions, so you could chain them.

Comment: Thank you. I'm asking this because @PitaJ here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73990867/how-to-know-if-the-stringsplit-is-on-one-char-or-another-inside-that-method?noredirect=1#comment130644260_73990867 said `Returning a value through a mutable reference parameter is very unidiomatic in Rust, and is probably leading to extra allocations in your code.` What does it mean?

Comment: In `c` you often pass a pointer to the function and this function modifies value behind the pointer. This is seldom done in rust. Here we usually take ownership of a value and then return modified one. But taking mutable reference, modifying it and returning this reference is quite common as well.

Comment: A common Rust pattern is to move away from conventional "set" mutators and instead have `x() -> &X` and `x_mut() -> &mut X` to allow read and write access respectively. For things like names that might need some clean-up first, make a `Name` you can pass in that ensures that whatever is set is already validated, as in you move that validation to `Name::new()` or `Name::from()`.

Comment: Wow @tadman. Thank you for this. It would be amazing to read an example of the code: can you write or post a link to an example? Please :pray:

Comment: @tadman I'm referring only to this part: `A common Rust pattern is to move away from conventional "set" mutators and instead have x() -> &X and x_mut() -> &mut X to allow read and write access respectively.` for a written example.

Comment: I don't know that there's a post per-se, but it's a pattern you'll see in a lot of Rust code, even Rust itself. For example, `Vec::retain` vs. `Vec::retain_mut` and `Option::as_deref` vs. `Option::as_deref_mut` where the `_mut` suffix means you get a mutable reference back for making modifications.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, if your function returns an entirely new value (like `fn to_name` as you implement it), you should return that value directly, rather than returning it through an "out reference". Rust has tuples, so you can even return multiple values directly from a function (unlike in C).

If your function modifies something in place, then you should take a mutable reference (like in `fn trim_all_spaces`) and maybe even return that mutable reference to enable chaining as Aleksander said.

Chaining example:

```
pub fn trim_all_spaces(s: &mut String) -> &mut String {
    s.retain(|c| !c.is_whitespace());
    s
}

// Usage: can call `&mut String` functions 
// on the returned mutable reference
trim_all_spaces(&mut s).truncate(12);
```

---

One more thing: `to_name` can be implemented as an in-place modification on the string instead of creating a new string:

```
pub fn to_name(s: &mut String) {
    trim_useless_space(s);

    s.retain(|c| c.is_whitespace() || c.is_alphabetic());

    let first_nonspace = s.find(char::is_alphabetic).unwrap_or(0);
    s.replace_range(..first_nonspace, "");
    s.truncate(s.trim().len());
}
```

Comment: Can you write an example for `If your function modifies something in place, then you should take a mutable reference (like in fn trim_all_spaces) and maybe even return that mutable reference to enable chaining as Aleksander said.`?

Comment: @FredHors edited to include a chaining example

Comment: Thanks. What do you think about using this kind of signature? `fn trim_all(mut s: String) -> String`?

Comment: If all it does is modify an existing string, then I'd probably change it to `s: &mut String`. If it creates a new string based on an existing one, it should probably take `s: &str` instead.

Comment: You don't like to the idea to take ownership and return ownership?

Comment: It's usually okay, but it can block optimization in some cases, so I generally avoid it when it's not necessary.

Comment: Wow. This is interesting. `block optimization`, what do you mean? The compiler's one?

Comment: Did you read this?

Comment: I guess "block optimization" may not be the right wording. But essentially, whenever you move a value (as opposed to passing a reference), the Rust compiler generates a `memcpy` which it then relies on the LLVM optimizer to remove down the line. There are likely cases where sufficiently complex pass-by-value functions may not be optimized as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I ask you what does it mean what @tadman said here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73991634/is-this-an-idiomatic-way-of-writing-these-helpers?noredirect=1#comment130648543_73991634: `A common Rust pattern is to move away from conventional "set" mutators and instead have x() -> &X and x_mut() -> &mut X to allow read and write access respectively.`?