# How to implement methods for structs in a different mod?

Tags: rust

Given the code in [this Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3968445c88e100f3503a788bb0793cb3):

```rust
mod domain {
    #[derive(Default, Clone)]
    pub struct Player {
        id: String,
        email: String,
    }
}

mod player {
    use crate::domain::Player;

    impl Player {
        pub fn set_email(&mut self, new_email: String) {
            self.email = new_email
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to fix the error:

```
error[E0616]: field `email` of struct `Player` is private
  --> src/main.rs:14:18
   |
14 |             self.email = new_email
   |                  ^^^^^ private field

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0616`.
```

I would like to implement some Struct methods in different mod (different files).

The structs are generated and all in a single file in the root dir.

I don't wanna use `pub` for fields because I need them to pass through `set_field` methods.

Comment: If the fields are private, you can't access them in a different module. You can make the field `pub(crate)` if you want, or call `set_field()`.

Comment: Yeah, but the `set_field()` is the problem here.

Comment: Why use a setter here? I understand [you want to validate the email before storing it in your struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73991634/is-this-an-idiomatic-way-of-writing-these-helpers), but with a type state pattern where your struct would store a strongly typed `Email` type that would be `TryFrom<String>`, validation would not be the responsibility of the Player struct anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please really reconsider keeping definition and implementation in the same module (file). This is de facto standard in the rust world. It will be easier to maintain and easier for someone new to your codebase to understand what's going on.

If you *really* insist on implementing methods in another module you can do it. But if you are going to use struct's private fields you will get the error you got. Solution here is to make this fields public in your other module. You can either mark your fields `pub(crate)` which will make them public anywhere *inside* your crate, or if you want to implement in *ancestor* module you can use `pub(in path::to::ancestor::module)`. You can read more about visibility and privacy [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html).